# How do I edit files in IIS7?

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7

> Disclaimer: I'm a complete IIS noob,
>   I've only dealt with Apache servers.

I have been given "full admin privileges" to RDP to a 3rd party server with IIS 7.0.6000 running on Windows Server 6.0 SP1. I'm trying to edit files in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webres\ however the directory has Read-Only permissions set.

In IIS manager I can Edit the permissions for the directory and uncheck the Read-Only box... however when I do it, it keeps reverting back.

If I try to edit a file with VIM it opens it in read-only obviously. The server is running, am I supposed to stop it in order to edit stuff or do I actually need to contact the administrator and tell them I need more permissions for my user which supposedly has full admin privileges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "read only" file attribute doesn't apply to directories, the bug of that checkbox being checked (and reverting to that) has been around for quite a while.

You should check NTFS permissions on the folder and files.

Answer (score 0):

Soo I ended up right clicking on the webres folder, properties, security tab, I selected one group of users and edited the permissions for the whole group, checked Modify and Write.. maybe the Admin forgot to do that but I can now read/write :)